# ObjectDataSource DataBinding does not contain a property with the name 'src' error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to bind a List as an ObjectDataSource to an asp:Repeater, here is the code:

```
namespace poster
{
  public static class ImageHandler
  {

    public struct imageStruct
    {
      public string src;
      //...
    }

    public static List<imageStruct> getSessionImages(string SessionID, string CurrentImageID = "*")
    {
      List<imageStruct> imgs = new List<imageStruct>();
        imageStruct img = new imageStruct
        {
          src = "xxx"
        };
     imgs.Add(img);
      //....
      return imgs;
    }
  }
}
```

aspx page:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="SessionImages" runat="server" DataSourceID="getSessionImages">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <img alt="" src="<%#Eval("src")%>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="getSessionImages" runat="server" SelectMethod="getSessionImages" TypeName="poster.ImageHandler">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:SessionParameter Name="SessionID" SessionField="SessionID" Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="*" Name="CurrentImageID" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Now I am stuck at the following error:

```
System.Web.HttpException: 'DataBinding: 'poster.ImageHandler+imageStruct' does not contain a property with the name 'src'.'
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to use getter and setter and it worked:

```
public struct imageStruct
{
  public string src  { get; set; }
  //...
}
```